# How to plot the probabilistic density function of a function?

Tags: r

Assume A  follows Exponential distribution; B follows Gamma distribution
How to plot the PDF of 0.5*(A+B)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is fairly straight forward using the "distr" package:

```
library(distr)

A <- Exp(rate=3)
B <- Gammad(shape=2, scale=3)

conv <- 0.5*(A+B)

plot(conv)
plot(conv, to.draw.arg=1)
```

***Edit by JD Long***

Resulting plot looks like this:
[image]

Comment: That's pretty neat. I was not familiar with the distr package.

Answer (score 7):

If you're just looking for fast graph I usually do the quick and dirty simulation approach. I do some draws, slam a Gaussian density on the draws and plot that bad boy:

```
numDraws   <- 1e6
gammaDraws <- rgamma(numDraws, 2)
expDraws   <- rexp(numDraws)
combined   <- .5 * (gammaDraws + expDraws)
plot(density(combined))
```

output should look a little like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt at doing the convolution (which @Jim Lewis refers to) in R. Note that there are probably much more efficient ways of doing this.

```
lower <- 0
upper <- 20
t <- seq(lower,upper,0.01)
fA <- dexp(t, rate = 0.4)
fB <- dgamma(t,shape = 8, rate = 2)
## C has the same distribution as (A + B)/2
dC <- function(x, lower, upper, exp.rate, gamma.rate, gamma.shape){
  integrand <- function(Y, X, exp.rate, gamma.rate, gamma.shape){
    dexp(Y, rate = exp.rate)*dgamma(2*X-Y, rate = gamma.rate, shape = gamma.shape)*2
  }
  out <- NULL
  for(ix in seq_along(x)){
    out[ix] <-
      integrate(integrand, lower = lower, upper = upper,
                X = x[ix], exp.rate = exp.rate,
                gamma.rate = gamma.rate, gamma.shape = gamma.shape)$value
  }
  return(out)
}
fC <- dC(t, lower=lower, upper=upper, exp.rate=0.4, gamma.rate=2, gamma.shape=8)
## plot the resulting distribution
plot(t,fA,
     ylim = range(fA,fB,na.rm=TRUE,finite = TRUE),
     xlab = 'x',ylab = 'f(x)',type = 'l')
lines(t,fB,lty = 2)
lines(t,fC,lty = 3)
legend('topright', c('A ~ exp(0.4)','B ~ gamma(8,2)', 'C ~ (A+B)/2'),lty = 1:3)
```

Comment: Don't bother generating the data from the functions, just plot the functions.  You'd use curve() instead of lines() with add = TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an R programmer, but it might be helpful to know that for independent random variables with PDFs f<sub>1</sub>(x) and f<sub>2</sub>(x), the PDF
of the sum of the two variables is given by the convolution f<sub>1</sub> * f<sub>2</sub> (x) of the two input PDFs.